# Too much bass in desktop sounds with a headset, but not during recording, only afterwards

Tags: audio, video-recording, audio-recording, audio-quality, obs

I recorded some video footages with my voiceover, both with **Fraps** and **OBS**. (Also streamed with the latter)

- While I was **playing** everything was **fine**. (I played with a headset)
- When I played the videos on my notebook **speaker**, they were **fine**.
- But when I played them with my **headset on**, they had **too much bass**. But only the **desktop sounds**. The mic input was fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an audio interface while recording?

Answer (score 0):

1. The fact that is sounds fine on your laptop speakers is probably because they do not reproduce much bass anyway.
2. To be sure that there is a difference in the recording, and the "live" sound, you could directly compare your recording after doing something like listening to a song on youtube, without changing volume. This allows you to go back and forth. If you're sure there is a difference you could post the example here.